# Caching false for twitter bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this simple demo to test bootstrap modal and JSON.

[Code](http://pastebin.com/sDTYHhAs)

When I click button "show", it loads the JSON and parses it.
And button "Launch demo modal" shows the parsed JSON.

But when I click the button "show" again,
the previous list in the modal is not removed and it appends with the current list 
increasing the size of the modal.

I want to refresh the cache everytime I click the "show" button.

Please help.

Comment: Please include the code *in* the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the code

```
    $('.ID1').html('');$('.ID2').html('');
```

below

```
    $getJSON
```

Will remove the cache from previous sessions and it works.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `.html()` instead of `.append()` . `.append()` adds  other `list` to your `modal` body, `.html(list)` instead, changes all the content of the `modal` body you're manipulating.
Otherwise you could `remove` all `.ID1` content and then refill it, but it is not such a good way to do.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.append()` use `$(".ID1").html(list);` this will replace the html of .ID1, while append will add to the current content.